# Access Subform with additional field but not editable

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I created an instructor form with a sub form table on the bottom - http://oi62.tinypic.com/20sa83m.jpg

I would like to add columns  in the subform from the instructor_info subform but it should not be editable, just display it as per the column relationship key, and the relationship key for the 2 tables (instructor_info & course_table) is course_id.

### Course Table

- Course Date (instead of Course)
- Course Location
- Station Demo
- No. of Teachings
- Hours Taught

### Instructor Teaching Info Table

- Instructor ID
- Alone
- Course
- Course Date
- No. of Teachings
- Course Type
- Notes

Comment: Change the 'LOCKED' and 'ENABLED' properties of the form controls to achieve what you want.

Comment: Hi Sir, Thanks for the reply. To some it up: I want to add columns below but only view it, basically the SQL a field for example is SELECT [Course Table].course_date FROM [Course Table] WHERE course_idColumn = [Course Table].course_id; 
For example, course date would be different per row since the course_date info is connected with the [Course Table].course_id

- Course Date (instead of Course)  course_date
- Course Location location
- Station Demo station_demo
- Hours Taught hours

Comment: I did my research, but it shows me Type mismatch in expression

is this right?

SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
RIGHT JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;

SELECT
a.instructor_id,
a.alone, 
a.course_id,
a.course,
a.num_teachings,
a.course_type,
a.notes,
b.course_date,
b.location,
b.station_demo,
b.hours
FROM [Instructor Teaching Information Table] as a
RIGHT JOIN [Course Table] as b
ON a.course_id = b.course_id;

Comment: One thing at a time please. Were you able to understand the LOCKED/ENABLED properties for your text boxes? As for your SQL problem, the fields you reference are NOT defined in the description of your two tables (i.e. where is 'Course_id'?). FYI, the Field & Table names should not contain spaces or special characters (.) - makes it a mess because brackets are always required!

Comment: If you have a "Tyoe Mismatch" error, it means just that; you're trying to join tables where the data types of the fields are different.  Make sure course_id has the same data type in both tables.

Comment: it's ok now @WayneG.Dunn, don't worry, those names are just the caption :)

Answer (score 0):

Gotcha! Here is what I did, I made the a.course_id enabled and all of the course table (b) are locked. Now when I change the course_id, every field follows :)

**SQL FOR Instructor Teaching Information**

```
SELECT
a.instructor_id,
a.alone, 
a.course_id,
a.num_teachings,
a.notes,

b.course_name,
b.course_type,
b.course_date,
b.location,
b.station_demo,
b.hours
FROM [Instructor Teaching Information Table] as a
RIGHT JOIN [Course Table] as b
ON a.course_id = b.course_id
```